# React router only works with root path

Tags: reactjs-flux, react-router, reactjs

Only root route works. /about, /home shows "Cannot GET /home" in browser. If i replace each route path with "/" then the corresponding component is rendering. But there seems to be problem when i try to render certain route eg /home.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure your server to work with `Router.HistoryLocation` -- that is, it needs to always serve your index.html page regardless of the route.

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});
```

Check out the docs here: [React Router Docs - HistoryLocation](https://rackt.github.io/react-router/#HistoryLocation)

Comment: i got the point, but with my limited knowledge of server configuration, it was hard for me to setup in "gulp-connect" server. I tried looking for other server like nginx, apache but could not find any thus ended up using HashLocation : 
Router.run(routes, Router.HashLocation, (Root) => { React.render(<Root/>, document.body) });

My point of using HistoryLocation was previously i was getting error in HashLocation : "missing )", which i managed to solve by importing "gulp-babel" in my gulpfile. 

thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm using a simple node server with express.. there's a lot of tutorials out there that could provide some more details.