# React Router only recognises index route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have 2 routes, `/` and `/about` and i've tested with several more. All routes only render the home component which is `/`.

When I try a route that doesn't exist it recognises that fine and displays the warning 
`Warning: No route matches path "/example". Make sure you have <Route path="/example"> somewhere in your routes`

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Router from 'react-router';
import { DefaultRoute, Link, Route, RouteHandler } from 'react-router';
import {Home, About} from './components/Main';

let routes = (
    <Route name="home" path="/" handler={Home} >
        <Route name="about" handler={About} />
    </Route>
);

Router.run(routes, function (Handler) {  
  React.render(<Handler/>, document.body);
});
```

**./components/Main**

```
import React from 'react';

var Home = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return <div> this is the main component </div>
    }
});

var About = React.createClass({
    render(){
        return <div>This is the about</div>
    }
});

export default {
    Home,About
};
```

I've tried adding an explicit path to about to no avail.
`<Route name="about" path="/about" handler={About} />`

I've stumbled upon this [stackoverflow Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32276514/react-router-only-works-with-root-path) but found no salvation in its answer.

Can anyone shed some light on what might be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've nested `About` under `Home` you need to render a `<RouteHandler />` component within your `Home` component in order for React Router to be able to display your route components.

```
import {RouteHandler} from 'react-router';

var Home = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (<div> this is the main component
            <RouteHandler />
        </div>);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Using ES6 and the newest react-router would look like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Router,
  Route,
  IndexRoute,
}
from 'react-router';

const routes = (
  <Router>
    <Route component={Home} path="/">
      <IndexRoute component={About}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
);

const Home = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div> this is the main component
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

//Remember to have your about component either imported or
//defined somewhere

React.render(routes, document.body);
```

On a side note, if you want to match unfound route to a specific view, use this:

```
<Route component={NotFound} path="*"></Route>
```

Notice the path is set to *

Also write your own NotFound component.

Mine looks like this:

```
const NotFound = React.createClass({
  render(){
   let _location = window.location.href;
    return(
      <div className="notfound-card">
        <div className="content">
          <a className="header">404 Invalid URL</a >
        </div>
        <hr></hr>
        <div className="description">
          <p>
              You have reached:
          </p>
          <p className="location">
            {_location}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```