# Redux + React : react router only rendering index route

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, children

I have tried following the answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32421598/react-router-only-recognises-index-route) but to no avail.
I am trying to use react router and nested routes to render different layouts depending on the configuration of the router. 
But the route with `path="/"` always shows regardless of the URL that is present.
Here is the router that I am using.

```
        <Route component={App}>
            <Route component={LayoutOne}>
                <Route path="/" component={ComponentOne}/>
            </Route>
            <Route component={LayoutTwo}>
                <Route path="category" component={ComponentTwo}/>
            </Route>
        </Route>
```

And here is the App file that I use to map the dispatch to the props, and connect.

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps){
    return{
        exampleProp: state.exampleProp,
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch);
}


const App = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MainLayout);

export default App;
```

Here is the main layout `MainLayout` as seen above.

```
export default class MainLayout extends Component {
    render(){
       <div className="main-layout">
            {this.props.children}
       </div>
    }
}
```

LayoutOne and LayoutTwo(has been omitted for brevity) are simple class rappers as follows.

export default class LayoutOne extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            
                    {this.props.children}
            
        )
    }
}

And here the ComponentOne and ComponentTwo respectively are just simple components.

My problem is that only ComponentOne renders regardless of what URL is present.
How do I fix this issue so that I could use nested routes as shown above?
Your help would be much appreciated.
If you need any additional information, please ask and I will do my best to update the question with the required information.
Thanks.

Comment: Just curious - does using `/category` work instead of `category`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're having is that the index route, i.e. `'/'`, is being matched first in your route tree, and because it matches any route, it is the route that gets rendered every time.

You can fix this by moving the `Route` with `path="category"` above the one with `path="/"`. This way the more detailed route option gets checked first. I would also recommend changing `path="category"` to `path="/category"` just for clarity's sake as both are root level routes.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your routes to look like this should fix your problem

```
<Route component={App} path="/">
    <Route component={LayoutOne} path="">
        <Route component={ComponentOne}/>
    </Route>
    <Route component={LayoutTwo} path="category">
        <Route component={ComponentTwo}/>
    </Route>
</Route>
```