# react-router only goes to index route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm running into a situation in react where my application on recognizes the index route.  my code in my app.js looks like this:

```jsx
import React from 'react'

import { render } from 'react-dom'

import { Router, Route, Link, IndexRoute } from 'react-router'

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <div>
                Hello There App
            </div>
          </div>
        );
    }
}   

class About extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <div>
                Hello There About
            </div>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

class Error extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <div>
                Hello There Error
            </div>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

React.render((
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={About}/>
      <Route path="*" component={Error}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.body)
```

There were some similar links I checked out:
[React Router only recognises index route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32421598/react-router-only-recognises-index-route)

and

[React router only works with root path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32276514/react-router-only-works-with-root-path)

But these didn't push me along.  I'm running an express server and I have a route there too:

```
app.use(ecstatic({ root: __dirname + '/public', handleError:true }));
app.get('/', function(request, response){
    response.sendfile("./public/index.html");
});
```

With or without the `app.get("/"...` I run into the same issue.  It's also worth noting that I tried it this way as well: https://github.com/rackt/react-router but my routes didn't work that way either.  I'm going on 4 days with this issue with endless research, hopefully one of you can point me in the right direction.

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.14.1",
    "browserify": "^10.2.6",
    "cors": "^2.7.1",
    "ecstatic": "~0.8.0",
    "express": "~4.0.0",
    "history": "^1.13.1",
    "mongoose": "~4.2.6",
    "react": "~0.13.3",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3",
    "react-router": "^1.0.0",
    "reactify": "^1.1.1",
    "socket.io": "^1.3.7",
    "uglify-js": "^2.4.24",
    "watchify": "^3.2.3"
  },
  "license": "public domain",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babelify": "^6.1.2"
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your routes look like:

```jsx
<Router>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Index}/>
    <Route path="*" component={Error}/>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

the other part you are missing is `{ this.props.children }` in your app component, where the nested route components should be mounted.

Check out the [master-detail](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/5d5f913d7156f59e3159f366fc6b9f2ac81285f9/examples/master-detail/app.js) example, where the *NotFound* route is used.

And on your server I would redirect everything `*` to index.html not only `/`:

```js
app.get('*', function(request, response){
    response.sendfile("./public/index.html");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm still getting the same issue.  I go to `http://localhost:8000/` which then ads some params to the URL `http://localhost:8000/#/?_k=3z6ymz` and then I get taken to my index route on the page that says `Hello There App` but then when I try going to `http://localhost:8000/about` it brings me to the error page (which is 404.html).  If I set handleError to false from within my server.js, it just simply says cannot GET that `about` route. When i go to `http://localhost:8000/#/about` I see `Hello There App again` with extra params `http://localhost:8000/#/about?_k=de8di9`

Comment: thanks a ton for your help on this one.  That's exactly what it was.  I added the `*` in my route, and then added `{ this.props.children }`.  Also, I was a little backwards in my Route logic, so thanks for clearing things up!